# Calloc memory being initialized to 0

Tags: c, calloc

I have a basic understanding of `calloc()`. It initializes the memory to 0, so why does this code:

```
table_t *table = calloc(1, sizeof(table_t));
printf("%d", *table);
```

I would expect this code to print 0, since I haven't put anything in that memory (I think); why does it give this error?

```
dictionary.c: In function ‘create_table’:
dictionary.c:11:14: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘table_t’ [-Werror=format=]
   11 |     printf("%d", *table);
      |             ~^   ~~~~~~
      |              |   |
      |              int table_t
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Does it make the memory 0 only for `int*`?

Comment: Show the full error message, but a `table_t`, whatever that is, presumably isn't an `int`.

Comment: Yes, it is a struct, not an int. I am just confused because if I just allocated the memory without putting anything there, shouldn't it print 0 if I dereference that location?

Comment: The warning is about the mismatch between the conversion specifier and the type of the argument to be printed. Such mismatches cause undefined behavior, and the compiler is helpfully providing a warning. This has nothing to do with `calloc`.

Comment: Like the error message says, you can't tell `printf()` that it's getting an `int` and then give it some other value instead.

Comment: Why would it print zero?  You're using `%d` for printing an `int`, **and it's not an `int`**.

Comment: My confusion is that I thought calloc() initialized the memory it allocates to 0. I was trying to print out what lives in that memory location (expecting 0); what calloc() initialized it to.

Comment: You need to learn to read the words in error messages. They convey information. They're not there just to take up space on the screen. It's pretty clear what **format '%d' expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘table_t’** means.

Comment: @Ken, thanks for your suggestion, I try to analyze errors to the best I can in the scope of my abilities. I see that the types don't match, I just anticipate 0's to live in that memory so I am unsure why %d, for an int would not work?

Comment: Because you're not passing it an `int`. You're passing it the contents of a pointer to a `struct`. That's what `table_t *table` means - pointer to a struct of type `table_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, the `%d` format specifier is expecting an `int` as an argument, but you're passing it a `table_t` instead.  Using the wrong format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.  It doesn't matter how the memory was initialized.

If you want to see what the memory looks like, you need to use an `unsigned char *` to iterate through the bytes and print that.

```
table_t *table = calloc(1, sizeof(table_t));
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(table_t); i++) {
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)table;
    printf("%d ", p[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Since the OP issue is with mismatch of argument and conversion specifier, maybe best to show `printf("%d ", p[i]);` --> `printf("%hhu ", p[i]);`.

Answer (score 3):

The memory pointed at by `table` will contain zeroes but `printf` [format specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) are typed.

`%d` expects an `int` not a `table_t` (presuming that doesn't resolve to some type of `int`).

It's not clear what the code is expected to do.  If the struct's first member is `int i` then you probably want this instead:

```
printf("%d", table->i)
```

Comment: Okay, I am starting to get it; an int member of the stuct was indeed init to 0. However, if I am just accessing the memory that calloc allocated, wouldn't 0's live there? With my logic if I am accessing a mem location init to 0, %d would work. Still fuzzy on this.

Comment: Passing `*(int*)table` should work, but it might be a violation of strict aliasing. You'd have to look at the code's disassembly to understand why passing a struct by value has this behavior. My guess is that it probably gets stored on the stack and then passed as a pointer via the variable args list, whereas an integer value would be passed as-is. Whatever happens, what you're really seeing here is undefined behavior.

Comment: @tothemax `%d` is not some generic number printer. It is a very specific, one-purpose thing, namely signed `int` integers, likely 32 bits wide. That's all it's good for - hand it anything else and it will not work. If you want to print _raw binary contents of memory cells_, that's a different story entirely. You would have to do that byte by byte and the mechanism for that in C is the `unsigned char`/`uint8_t` type, as shown in another answer.

Comment: @paddy Advanced topic and not for the OP, but no it's actually not a strict aliasing violation since the memory returned from `calloc` has no effective type. So you can do `*(int*)table` just fine, assuming that alignment is ok. But if you would later on try to access it through the intended type `table`, _then_ you might get strict aliasing violations because the first access mucked up the effective type.